# More Succinct Option Comparison

Tags: rust

Supposing I have two option-wrapped variables, is there a better way to compare them than this?

```rust
fn comp(a: Option<i32>, b: Option<i32>) -> bool {
    match a {
        Some(ai) => match b {
            Some(bi) => ai == bi,
            _ => false,
        },
        None => match b {
            None => true,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to lose the case where they might both be `None` and therefore equal, but this seems like a lot of matching for a relatively simple thing. I'm also trying to avoid `unwrap()`.

Comment: The given answer is right, but to give you a `match` based solution that shows how expressive `match` can be... note that you can even match on a tuple: `match (a, b) { (Some(ai), Some(bi)) => ai == bi, (None, None) => true, _ => false }`. This is really handy when you need to look at 2-3 values and handle certain combinations.

Comment: @cdhowie Oh, yes! That is useful. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Option`s [can be compared directly](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#impl-Eq), so you can [simply return `a == b`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=993156749b137711b81e7256a2538ba4).

Comment: Oh, dang. Rust once again surprises me with how ergonomic it is. I feel dumb for not thinking to just try the straightforward way.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, if `T: PartialEq`, `Option<T>: PartialEq` and if `T: Eq`, `Option<T>: Eq`. See this example ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=53daa36619dbdf5fe977c91dbf894b42)):

```rust
fn main() {
    assert_eq!(Some(3), Some(3));
    assert_ne!(Some(3), None);
    assert_eq!(None, None);
    assert_ne!(Some(3), Some(4));
}
```